# How to create an array from a hash that has elements and frequencies

Tags: ruby

I have a hash where each key corresponds to its frequency:

```
hsh = {'a' => 2, 'b' => 3, 'c' => 1}
```

which I want to break down into an array:

```
arr = ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c']
```

I used the following approach which works fine, but is there a better way to do it?

```
arr = []
hsh.each do |x,y|
  y.times do
    arr << x
  end
end
```

Comment: If the code works and you want a better way you should consider using [codereview.se] instead of [so].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a one liner like:

```
hsh.map { |k,v| Array.new(v,k) }.flatten
```

*map iterates as `each` and returns an array with the result of each iteration*. For each entry, you create a new array with of `v` elements with default value `k`. As the result of `map` will be an array of arrays, you need to flatten it.

or

```
hsh.each_with_object([]) do|(k, v),arr| 
  v.times { arr << k }
end
```

*`each_with_object` iterates and gives you an object as well, which you pass initially*. Typically you use this object to accumulate data. It's similar to yours but you don't have to initialize the array in another line

But honestly, they don't look very readable.

Answer (score 8):

```
arr = hsh.flat_map { |k, v| [k] * v }
#=> ["a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "c"]
```

Comment: And it's all there is to it. Not sure there is a better/simpler approach :)

Comment: or `hsh.flat_map { |*k, v| k * v }`

Answer (score 0):

Your approach seems fine, but you can also write it like this

```
hash.flat_map { |k,v| v.times.map { k } }
```